# Vue Element.ui tree, emit reload event

Tags: javascript, mongoose, vue.js, tree, element-ui

I create a SPA on Vue (something like a cloud disk), using the [Element.ui tree](http://element-cn.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/tree) component, to display the folder tree. The problem is that the tree itself does not load everything at once, but is loaded sequentially with the help of the lazy modifier.

The server part is  mongoose + mongoose-path-tree. The use of the mongoose-path-tree means, that a tree storage scheme in the database is next: each node does not know about its children, but the children store their full path to the root element:

```
#root_id #subroot_id # ... #parent_id #this_id
```

**The problem** is that if the user makes changes to the tree (loads the file, creates a new folder, etc.) and the server accepts them, then how to notify the tree that it needs to load new data. Element ui in its documentation does not describe how to capture an event to cause the redrawing of a tree.

Client tree template

```
<el-tree
 :props="defaultProps"
 :load="loadNode"
 @node-click="handleNodeClick"
 :expand-on-click-node="false"
 lazy
 node-key="id"
 ref="tree"
 />
```

Loading new nodes

```
loadNode: async function (node, resolve) {
try {
  let firstGeneration = await foldersAPI.get(this.$store.state.user.myDrive);
  if (node.level === 0) {
    return resolve(firstGeneration.data.folder.children);
  } else {
    var data;
    if (node.data.hasChildren) {
      let children = await foldersAPI.get(node.data._id);
      console.log(children);
      data = children.data.folder.children;
    } else {
      data = [];
    }
    resolve(data);
  }
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e)
}
```

Comment: I agree that at least we need something to reload Element components when we need.

Answer (score 6):

My solution was to simply rerender the treeview by adding the v-if attribute to the treeview and then creating a method

```
reload() {
    this.show = false;
    this.$nextTick(() => {
         this.show = true
    })
}
```

Calling that reload function then properly reloads the treeview

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass computed variable as prop for tree component. All changes in computed will trigger rerender of tree.

Comment: But I use lazy load,  so I can't use computed props. Ecsual, I can't get data from tree component, if I use lazy load with element-ui tree

Comment: I tried to put data array into computed, it can get the data, put it up, but cannot display them out. dingoglotz's solution works for me.

Answer (score 0):

you can set a `key` property to the component, and then, just change the `key` value, the component will re-render.

```
<el-tree
 :props="defaultProps"
 :load="loadNode"
 @node-click="handleNodeClick"
 :expand-on-click-node="false"
 lazy
 node-key="id"
 ref="tree"
 :key="myKey"
 />
```

read the doc for more details: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#Controlling-Reusable-Elements-with-key